# Website being displayed in root and subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

My website is being displayed at two locations: one in the root like www.website.com like I want it to, and the other is displayed at www.website.com/wordpress, which I don't want.

In the folder structure of my website, I installed WordPress in a subdirectory called wordpress, copied the index.php file to the root, and amended this to make it point at the subdirectory: `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Is this normal behaviour, and can I somehow have my website be display only at www.website.com?

Comment: Have you changed the WordPress address (URL) to http://example.com/wordpress?

Comment: Yes, I just looked at my dashboard, and the WordPress Address Url is set to http://website.com/wordpress, while I have Site Address Url set to http://website.com.

Comment: Try resetting your permalinks to default, and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: I just pressed save on the Permalink page of the dashboard, since I had not made any changes concerning permalinks, but it does not seem to make the issue go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spun up a development instance, and tried going through the process, and I got the same result. I was able to fix it by renaming the `index.php` that is **NOT** in the root to `useless.php`. That made the /wordpress portion of the site 503, and it kept the root portion of the site running. Try it and let me know if it works!

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, thank you! Thanks for the effort of spinning up a development instance and checking it. Would like to know though, is this okay behaviour, the 503?

Comment: Yep, the 503 is simply a forbidden error, saying they don't have permission to access the directory. It is standard behavior and shouldn't cause any issues whatsoever. If this solved your problem, please accept my answer :)